Does a Rejected Asylum Application in the UK Impact Future Travel and Visa-Free Entry?
I have a hypothetical question about the implications of a rejected asylum application in the UK. If someone applies for asylum in the UK, and their application is ultimately rejected at all stages (by the Home Office and on appeal in court), would this have any impact on their ability to travel in the future?
For instance, if they hold a passport that allows visa-free travel to certain countries, would those countries still admit them after their asylum claim has been denied in the UK? Could the rejected application history create any complications when traveling or entering visa-free countries and ones that need a visa? Will they find problems when applying for residency permits or citizenship by investment programs in other countries.
Additionally, if the person cannot return to their country of citizenship for personal safety reasons, would it still be feasible for them to rely on visa-free travel options, or might they face issues at the border?
I’m curious about how this scenario might play out and whether such a history could create obstacles in practice.
Thanks in advance for any insights or information!

This seems a bit hypothetical, since the personal circumstances of most asylum seekers mean they don't qualify for regular visas anyway (no ties to homeland etc).

@lambshaanxy but what about going to visa free countries?

You're asking "could" - the answer is yes, it could. "Would" though is a different question, and the answer to that would be wildly speculative.

While this is all very hypothetical, I think the main issue is whether those other countries will know about it or not (but it may also depend on the country).
If they do know about it, expect a refusal. Most countries which are usual destinations for asylum seekers (both “real” and “fake” ones) have a strong aversion towards them. They know they have to accept the real ones, but they would prefer not to. And they loathe the “fake” ones who take advantage of the system to stay in their destination country for as long as possible while all appeals are processed, often for years, while they benefit from help from the government, even though there may be no valid reason at all for it.
So someone who has gone through the process in one country and has been rejected is definitely not someone they want to welcome. While for a refugee the presumption should be that they are a real one, in this case it would be a lot more difficult to accept.
Note how many countries set up things like airport/airside transit visas just to make sure people don’t try to claim asylum while in transit. And of course a big part of the screening in the visa process is to avoid letting people who are going to claim asylum once they’re in. Having already done so and been rejected clearly does not play in one’s favour.
Now, whether they will know about it or not is a big mystery. Some will explicitly ask about it, but of course you can always lie (or try to, anyway). Some will be able to rely on information sharing with other countries. Sometimes the applicant’s circumstances will make it obvious. I certainly wouldn’t count on going under the radar.
Additionally, after the large influx of refugees due to the various recent crises, and the “open door” policies of many countries, there is an even stronger anti-immigrant sentiment in many countries (look at the scores of the far right in many recent elections), which means a tightening of rules. A person who has already claimed asylum and has been rejected is definitely very very low on the scale of people they are willing to admit.

While this describes the political realities in many Western countries, large numbers of refugees/asylum seekers are actually staying in their regions, in countries like Lebanon (!), Jordan, Congo, Iran (!), Pakistan.

@o.m. That's what I was hinting at with "but it may also depend on the country" but I didn't develop it as I'm not familiar with their rules and policies.
